# Is there a way to re-trigger the thread's originating event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to introduce a modal to confirm a user's intent before proceeding.  In order to do this dynamically, I'd like the original call-stack to trigger from the very start.  For example, if someone submits a form and I'm doing something like this:

```
 jQuery('form').submit(function() {
     var positive = sure("Are you sure you want to submit this form?");
     return positive;
 });
```

Then my `sure` function might look like this:

```
var confirmed_sure = false;
function sure(input) {
        if(confirmed_sure) return true;
        var html = jQuery('html');

        var code = "<div id='sure'>"+
                    "<div id='sure_inner'>"+
                        input+
                        "<br style='clear: both;' />"+
                        "<div id='sure_yes'>OK</div>"+
                        "<div id='sure_no'>Cancel</div>"+
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>"+
            "</div>";
        jQuery(html).append(jQuery(code));

        var orig = sure.caller; // trying to get the original trigger
        jQuery('#sure_yes').click(function() {
            confirmed_sure = true; // set this bit so when we recursively call below it won't loop
            jQuery('#sure').remove();

            setTimeout(function() {
                return orig(); // this is the part I want to re-fire the form submit
            });
        });
        jQuery('#sure_no').click(function() {
            jQuery('#sure').remove();
            return false;
        });

        return false;
}
```

Notice I have the `orig()` call, which is utilizing [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) (I know it's deprecated; if there's a better option I'm all ears!) to try to get the original function, but it's not QUITE working how I want it to.

I see in the DevTools when I put in breakpoints on the `var positive` line that it IS being hit a second time from the `orig()` call, but it doesn't re-submit the form.  I'm thinking that's because I'm re-executing the anonymous function INSIDE the submit() call, but not the submit() call itself.

I have tried using `sure.caller.caller`, `sure.caller.arguments.callee.caller`, `arguments.callee.caller.caller` and `arguments.callee.caller.arguments.callee.caller` to define `orig`, but no matter what I cannot seem to re-trigger the original submit query.

So my question is: is there a way I can store, then execute the originating event which caused the original JavaScript stack in a programmatic way? (For this example I used it was `submit()`, but in other cases it might be `click()` or something else.)

---

**UPDATE FROM CONVERSATION**: Yes, this is technically possible, if hacky. It relies upon depreciated (but still supported) caller and arguments. Basically just need to re-work the `orig` value to be a target+type pair, and call that to re-execute, like so:

```
  var orig_target = new_confirm.caller.arguments[0].originalEvent.target;
  var orig_type = new_confirm.caller.arguments[0].originalEvent.type;
  jQuery('#sure_yes').click(function() {
       sure_confirmed = true;
       jQuery('#sure_confirm').remove();
       setTimeout(function() { jQuery(orig_target).trigger(orig_type); }, 1);
  });
```

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. Instead of trying to mess with the call stack, let the caller pass in a continuation callback that should be called when the confirmation succeeded: `$('form').submit(e => { e.preventDefault(); sure("Are you …?", () => this.submit()); })`. In other cases, you can pass `() => this.click()` or whatever is necessary to trigger the original action.

Comment: `submit` must return synchronously, so its return value will already be defined before the user clicks. That function will no longer be on the call stack by the time the user clicks. As Bergi indicated, you'll need to cancel the submission now and then submit later when the user has confirmed.

Comment: @Bergi I can programmatically submit a form (`jQuery('form').submit();`), and if I can see the whole call stack, then what is the blocking factor from re-executing the original trigger? --- Given the number of places in my existing code that would need to be touched (including a ton of inline `<a onclick="confirm('Are you sure?');" href=...` segments) this is why I'm trying to leave the originating calls as untouched as possible, sorry if I seem to be pushing this issue, just looking to genericize this solution to allow a single-point fix.

Comment: @Bing The blocking factor is that you *should not* look at the call stack to figure out what your function should do. It's just a horrible practice. If you want a more clever solution than passing a callback, pass the event object, and derive from that what your function should do after the confirmation. `$('form').submit(e => sure("Are you …?", e));`  and `function sure(event) { …; $(event.target)[event.type](); }`.

Comment: @Bergi So this is a "shouldn't" not a "can't" then?  There is a way, it's just bad practice because the function should never operate "upstream"?  Is there a reason this is so taboo?  I'm not sure if the "bad practice" stigma alone is enough justification for me to spend the days re-working these (including, as I said, the inline `<a onclick="return confirm('You sure?')" href...` blocks) .

Comment: @Bing No, I think it's also a "cannot" (as you already figured out there is no standard API for such things), but I might be proven wrong. Maybe you can somehow extract the name "onclick" from a stack trace, maybe you can utilise the global `window.event` (except in Firefox), but even if you can it will be horrible, hacky and fragile. You will spend more days fighting bugs and finding obscure workarounds than days needed to do it properly. Passing in the event object is not hard.

Comment: @Bing ... since you need to be convinced. Working with the `this` context of a jQuery callback (the submit handler) and/or with the `event` object which gets passed into this very callback is also much cleaner / more transparent / far less complicated in comparison to the approach you choose to start with.

Comment: @Bergi I was able to figure it out (using `caller`) thanks to your `function sure(event) { …; $(event.target)[event.type](); }` example, so it is technically possible after all.  Given the depreciated nature of `caller` (and not wanting to be a "bad programmer") I'll be trying to implement your example with passing the `event` itself, however I will be amending my question to show the working code.

Comment: Please post your update as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE FROM CONVERSATION:** Yes, this is technically possible, if hacky. It relies upon depreciated (but still supported) caller and arguments. Basically just need to re-work the `orig` value to be a target+type pair, and call that to re-execute, like so:

```
  var orig_target = new_confirm.caller.arguments[0].originalEvent.target;
  var orig_type = new_confirm.caller.arguments[0].originalEvent.type;
  jQuery('#sure_yes').click(function() {
       sure_confirmed = true;
       jQuery('#sure_confirm').remove();
       setTimeout(function() { jQuery(orig_target).trigger(orig_type); }, 1);
  });
```